# Filter React children by type with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to build a Wrapper for some other component and for that I try to filter *React children* by type:

```
// Component
const SubComponent = (props: SubComponentProps) => <NestedComponent {...props} />;

const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
    const { children } = props;
    const arrayChildren = React.Children.toArray(children);

    // doesn't work, but the type is right (child.type === SubComponent)
    const content = React.Children.count(arrayChildren) && arrayChildren.find((child) => React.isValidElement(child) && child.type === SubComponent);

    // works, but the type complains (child.type.name === "SubComponent")
    const content2 = React.Children.count(arrayChildren) && arrayChildren.find((child) => React.isValidElement(child) && child.type.name === "SubComponent");

    return (
        <Something {...props}>
            {/* Type complains, but works */}
            {content && <SomethingElse>{content.props.children}</SomethingElse>}
        </Something>
    );
};

MyComponent.SubComponent = SubComponent;

export default MyComponent;

// Usage
<MyComponent>
    <MyComponent.SubComponent>
        Some Stuff
    </MyComponent.SubComponent>
</MyComponent>
```

Why doesn't `child.type` match?

And why doesn't `child.type.name` exist on the type, even though it works? (The type of the child is given as `React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> And why doesn't child.type.name exist on the type, even though it works? (The type of the child is given as React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal)

After you check for `React.isValidElement(..)` you basically narrow the type of `child` to `React.ReactElement`. And the issue with `React.ReactElement` is that it could have either a `string` or a function-contructor as the value to its `type` field. As you probably know, a `string` does not have a `name` property on it, thus you get an error. Actually, the expected constructor definition type provided by React typings is not considered as ordinary function as well (I guess it's something the lib authors could improve upon).

So I'd say, the simplest solution is just to cast the type to a function, like this:

```
(child.type as unknown as () => void).name === "SubComponent"
```

This will compile.

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for the late reaction), this gets me one step closer to solving this :-)

Comment: How do you access only the `type` (without the `name`)? typescript is complaining